# Virtual filesystem in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a virtual filesystem layer in Perl. Something that would provide a general abstraction for basic filesystem routines like `ls`, `mkdir` and so on, regardless how the actual filesystem is implemented.

I'd like an interface like this:

```
# create a directory "/some/path/tmp" in my current filesystem
my $plainfs = Module::new->(type => 'local', root=>'/some/path);
$plainfs->mdkir("/tmp"); 

# create "tmp" dir on a remote filesystem
my $sshfs = Module::new->(type=>'ssh', root=>'user:password@example.com:~/pub')
$sshfs->mdkir("/tmp");
```

I found [the VFS package](https://metacpan.org/release/VFS) on MetaCPAN, unfortunately there are only empty, unimplemented modules.

Is something already implemented? Right now, I'm looking for only “local” filesystems and ftp or ssh—I don't need a database “filesystem” or any other exotic “filesystem” like CVS or so. Searching 20k MetaCPAN modules is painful without any tagging system or alike…

Comment: File::System looks good: http://search.cpan.org/~hanenkamp/File-System-1.16/

Comment: @perreal This loooks really nice. Going to check deeper. How do you find it? I'm searching METACPAN for "filesystem" an this package is not showed in first 7 pages. ;( Metacpan search is REALLY TERRIBLE. Thank you very much.

Comment: @kobame while it could be suggested I worked backwards from the answer, if I search for "file system" (no quotes) on MetaCPAN this is the first result. The search is excellent IME, but it can only work with the data it has and the input you give it

Comment: For dealing with remote servers Rex looks pretty good: https://www.rexify.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [File::System](http://search.cpan.org/~hanenkamp/File-System-1.16/lib/File/System.pm) is what you're looking for. It provides basic functionalities found in common operating systems for managing a virtual file system (not necessarily comprised only of files and directories).

Most of the functionalities are presented as method of the [File::System::Object](http://search.cpan.org/~hanenkamp/File-System-1.16/lib/File/System/Object.pm) package.

Answer (score 1):

what about some FUSE implementation? ( file system in userspace ) ? I would guess there is at least one pseudo-filesystem implemented in perl based on that. After all, it should be quite easy to implement, basically it's no more than some set of operations like mount, ls, df, stat and so on. I was once through autofs sources in C, looked pretty straightforward. You might want to see http://code.google.com/p/mogilefs/ as well.

Comment: I don't want 'implement' filesystem, but *use* already done implementations, so looking for a module what already done the abstraction. Probably it is "doable", but hoping in something what is already done :) Going to check mogilefs - thanx for the pointer.

Comment: just take any userspace filesystem, and get rid of what it's supposed to do under every basic operation internals, on some top level, perhaps by putting "return true" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be too stuck up on the module approach. All you need is some utility that mounts SSH/FTP filesystem as a local filesystem and then you will simply use standard commands like cd, mkdir and so on. The reason why you don't see any modules for this is that this approach is generally preferred.

Look at http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems

You will simply use FUSE to mount any of those file systems and that is it. Here are some links to look at, but most of those can be got as packages in most distributions too.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/lufs/
http://lftpfs.sourceforge.net

Here is module to simply mount FUSE file systems within perl:

http://search.cpan.org/~dpavlin/Fuse/Fuse.pm

Answer (score 0):

There are a LOT of File::* modules which handle different parts of cross-platform filesystem management.

For example:

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile);
```

Will let you get my $filename = catfile $root, $path, "$filename.$ext"; or my $new_directory = catfile $path, "new_sub_directory"; and be sure to use the correct separators, e.g. / or \, et cetera.

Another thing you seem to want can be had with:

```
use File::Path qw(make_path);
```

which is pretty handy, and can be called like make_path($new_directory, { mode => 0755 });

I'm not really sure if File::System actually handles remote systems the way you want.

A couple different ways occur to me to handle that, but I think Net::SSH::Expect is what I've used in the past, and isn't too bad, although you'd probably have an easier time if you could somehow mount the remote filesystem locally, do what you have to do, then unmount it.